# Boost fsm and Boost statechart path location

Tags: c++, boost, fsm

I wanted to implement a simple fsm using boost. i read the boost fsm doc [here](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/fsm/doc/state_machine.html) but I couldnt locate the header files. is the fsm library and other template classes located in boost statechart folder ? When I did a find in the subdirectories, I found this:

```
 boost version: 1.55

 find . -name state_machine.hpp    
 ./boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp
 ./boost/spirit/home/support/detail/lexer/state_machine.hpp
 ./boost/statechart/state_machine.hpp
 ./libs/mpl/example/fsm/state_machine.hpp
```

Which one should I use to implement a simple FSM?

Also I couldnt find the turnstile example which they said is supposed to be in libs/fsm/examples/Turnstile  folder.

Can anyone please tell me the correct path and location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay. i understood that boost.fsm was not accepted and hence not included in the pack. boost.msm and boost.statechart was added instead. if anyone wants to have boost.fsm here is the github link provided to me (boost-users mailing list) by the author Andrey Semashev. Thanks Andrey for this. here is the link:

[boost.fsm](https://github.com/Lastique/fsm)